# Ubuntu 16.04 lightdm segmentation fault

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, libc, xserver

I'm newbie into Linux world, and i have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 with graphics driver for Cirrus Logic 5440 graphics card. What happened, I could not start X-server, Lightdm display manager breaks on segmentation fault caused by libc.so.6, this is part of Xorg0.log log file:

```
[   684.494] (EE) Backtrace:
[   684.494] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x557fcc97c6ce]
[   684.494] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x557fcc7ca000+0x1b6a69) [0x557fcc980a69]
[   684.494] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f6db03c3000+0x354b0) [0x7f6db03f84b0]
[   684.494] (EE)
[   684.494] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[   684.494] (EE) Fatal server error:
[   684.494] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

Could someone help me, I can't see what is wrong. Libc is installed and exist in /lib and /lib64 directory. Thanks very much!

Comment: You might want to try asking this on Ask Ubuntu, I'm sure they will be able to help you much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a reported and fixed bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-openchrome/+bug/1577573)

To fix it, run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

Install the dependent packages for OpenChrome

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
```

clone the OpenChrome repository to your device:

```
$ git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/openchrome/xf86-video-openchrome
```

After you finish cloning it, cd into it.

```
$ cd xf86-video-openchrome
```

Generate any needed scripts

```
$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --enable-debug --enable-xv-debug --enable-viaregtool
```

If there were no errors, compile OpenChrome

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I'm using xf86-video-dummy video driver. I know he could not show anything but I need him to start lightdm service.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling lightdm everything works fine now. This is working great, I don't know why but it's working!